# Oracle Thin Driver and Transparent Failover of RAC DB

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, failover

I know the oci driver can perform transparent failover of the database, but does the thin driver have the same capability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Thin driver does not support TAF like the OCI driver does as is described in the [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/htdocs/jdbc_faq.html#34_06).

When using the Thin driver, the built-in RAC capability of Fast Connection Failover is available:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/fstconfo.htm